# How Do You Pass a Variable to Curl in Bash Script

Tags: bash, api, curl

## How Do You Pass a Variable to Curl in Bash Script

I'm not able to get this curl to work in a bash script using an environment variable. The API key gets misinterpreted somehow when passed in via a variable and I'm getting authentication errors on submit. If I plug in the API key with no surrounding quotes as plaintext, this works just fine. I've tried various forms of escaping quotes and other combinations. Any help would be great.

**Code**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source .env

curl -X POST https://api.easypost.com/v2/shipments \
  -u "$EASYPOST_TEST_API_KEY": \
  -d 'shipment[to_address][name]=Dr. Steve Brule' \
  -d 'shipment[to_address][street1]=179 N Harbor Dr' \
  -d 'shipment[to_address][city]=Redondo Beach' \
  -d 'shipment[to_address][state]=CA' \
  -d 'shipment[to_address][zip]=90277' \
  -d 'shipment[to_address][country]=US' \
  -d 'shipment[to_address][phone]=8573875756' \
  -d 'shipment[to_address][email]=dr_steve_brule@gmail.com' \
  -d 'shipment[from_address][name]=EasyPost' \
  -d 'shipment[from_address][street1]=417 Montgomery Street' \
  -d 'shipment[from_address][street2]=5th Floor' \
  -d 'shipment[from_address][city]=San Francisco' \
  -d 'shipment[from_address][state]=CA' \
  -d 'shipment[from_address][zip]=94104' \
  -d 'shipment[from_address][country]=US' \
  -d 'shipment[from_address][phone]=4153334445' \
  -d 'shipment[from_address][email]=support@easypost.com' \
  -d 'shipment[parcel][length]=20.2' \
  -d 'shipment[parcel][width]=10.9' \
  -d 'shipment[parcel][height]=5' \
  -d 'shipment[parcel][weight]=65.9' \
```

Comment: The only thing I see wrong is the `\ ` on the last line of your command.  Why the `:` after your api key?  To debug, add `echo` in from of your curl command, to print it out, exactly like the script builds it.  Or add `-x` to your bash 1st line.  What is the key itself?  Are there any special characters in there?

Comment: It's what the docs call for, without it, curl asks for the host password for user "MY_API_KEY_HERE". Echoing the curl command does show the api key in there as it should be... actually running it though gives an API key error.

Comment: @JustinHammond `echo` can hide things like whitespace and nonprinting characters. Adding `-x` to the shebang (or putting `set -x` before the `curl` command) will show oddities more reliably.

Comment: @GordonDavisson doing that shows that the env file is sourced correctly but that it is not passed in where the variable is.

Comment: It's hard to tell what might cause that without seeing everything involved. I'd recommend trying to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem. Basically, this means making a duplicate of all the scripts etc involved, then trying to remove/simplify everything that isn't part of the problem itself (e.g. replace the `curl` command with just `echo "$EASYPOST_TEST_API_KEY":`, inline the `source`d file, etc) bit by bit. If you remove something and the problem goes away, put it back because it *is* part of the problem.

Comment: With the problematic script stripped down to its bare minimum, the problem is usually obvious; if it isn't, add the minimal script(s) to your question so someone else can try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Gordon Davisson's suggestion to break it down into a minimal request, it started sending right. Then I rebuilt it just as in my question above and for whatever reason it worked like a charm. The `-x` flag was also incredibly helpful in troubleshooting this but come to find out there wasn't anything inherently wrong with it in the first place. Thanks for everyone's responses!